# Getting Text out of a child element trapped in an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am a JavaScript Newbie!

It took me the entire day to code a Javascript driven Slider! I didn't want to use the Bootstrap Carousel. The Slider has 4 pictures and each picture has a Text above that picture. The Slider navigates through the Pictures and the belonging Text. All these Pictures are in divs with `class="rtype"`. In each of these rtype `divs` there is a `span` with the description. The Spans have no id.

The Slider is working perfectly! No issues there!

What i am trying to do:

I want Javascript (jQuery) to read the text out of that description (`span`) and display it in a `td`. The `td` has an `id="rt"`

So whenever i click on next or previous, 3 things should happen:

1. Change Picture (working)
2. Change Description (working)
3. Extract Description text from the slider and display it in a `td` that has absolutely nothing to do with the slider (not working)

All of this and more is in a single html file. As of now the entire website consists of one html file only.

The HTML Slider Code:

```
<div id="minc" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">

<div class="rtype text-center" style="display: block;">
<a href=""><img class="lb img-responsive pull-left" src="img/l.png" alt=""/></a><span><strong>SINGLE ROOM</strong></span>
<a href=""><img class="rb img-responsive pull-right" src="img/r.png" alt=""/></a>
<img class="img-responsive" src="img/SR.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>

<div class="rtype text-center" style="display: none;">
<a href=""><img class="lb img-responsive pull-left" src="img/l.png" alt=""/></a><span><strong>DOUBLE ROOM</strong></span>
<a href=""><img class="rb img-responsive pull-right" src="img/r.png" alt=""/></a>
<img class="img-responsive" src="img/DR.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>  

<div class="rtype text-center" style="display: none;">
<a href=""><img class="lb img-responsive pull-left" src="img/l.png" alt=""/></a><span><strong>TWIN ROOM</strong></span>
<a href=""><img class="rb img-responsive pull-right" src="img/r.png" alt=""/></a>
<img class="img-responsive" src="img/TR.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>  

<div class="rtype text-center" style="display: none;">
<a href=""><img class="lb img-responsive pull-left" src="img/l.png" alt=""/></a><span><strong>FAMILY ROOM</strong></span>
<a href=""><img class="rb img-responsive pull-right" src="img/r.png" alt=""/></a>
<img class="img-responsive" src="img/FR.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>      

</div>
```

The Javascript Navigation Code:

```
<script>

$(function(){
$(".lb").click(function () {
var no_slides = $('.rtype').length;
var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
var current = $('.rtype').index(parent);
var prev = no_slides - 1;
if (current > 0) {
prev = current - 1;
}
$('.rtype').hide();
$('.rtype:eq(' + prev + ')').show();
return false;
});
})



$(function(){
$(".rb").click(function () {
var no_slides = $('.rtype').length;
var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
var current = $('.rtype').index(parent);
var next = 0;
if (current < no_slides - 1) {
next = current + 1;
}

$('.rtype').hide();
$('.rtype:eq(' + next + ')').show();
return false;
});
})  
</script>
```

I had no success with Tree Traversal in the above mentioned Javascript Code the following way:

```
<script>
$(function(){
$(".rb").click(function () {
var no_slides = $('.rtype').length;
var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
var current = $('.rtype').index(parent);

--> var text = $(this).children('.span').text(); <--
--> $( "#rt" ).text(text); <--

var next = 0;
if (current < no_slides - 1) {
next = current + 1;
}

$('.rtype').hide();
$('.rtype:eq(' + next + ')').show();
return false;
});
})
```

Can you guys please help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Recreate it on https://jsfiddle.net/ so we can try to get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the description of the slide by changing your code slightly when you show the next slide:

```
var text = $('.rtype:eq(' + next + ')').show().find("span").text();
$("#rt").text(text);
```

That should work. Your `span`s are not children of the elements with class `rb`, so what you have won't work. Also, you don't want the `.` in there because you are searching for an `span` element, not a class.

Since you have already found the next slide, you can chain your jQuery to find the span descendant, then set the text.

Comment: Thanks for answering Dave! Now it is showing the description but not of the current slide but the previous slide. The Description above the slide and the description in td are not the same. Any ideas?

Comment: Thank You Sir!! You are my Hero of the Week! It is now working perfectly =)

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of Completeness:

This is how the Slider Navigation Code must look like:

```
<script>
$(function(){
$(".lb").click(function () {
var no_slides = $('.rtype').length;
var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
var current = $('.rtype').index(parent);
var prev = no_slides - 1;
if (current > 0) {
prev = current - 1;
}
$('.rtype').hide();
var text = $('.rtype:eq(' + prev + ')').show().find("span").text();
$( "#rt" ).text(text);
return false;
});
})



$(function(){
$(".rb").click(function () {
var no_slides = $('.rtype').length;
var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
var current = $('.rtype').index(parent);
var next = 0;
if (current < no_slides - 1) {
next = current + 1;
}
$('.rtype').hide();
var text = $('.rtype:eq(' + next + ')').show().find("span").text();
$( "#rt" ).text(text);
return false;
});
})  
</script>
```

Thank You Dave! It is working now!